# Can't get AJAX on file upload working

Tags: forms, ajax, files

I have a `managed_file` form element. I want to trigger an AJAX callback when a user clicks the upload button. But I can't seem to get anything working by attaching the `#ajax` element to the `managed_file` element. I know the `managed_file` element creates an upload button automatically, so I tried to hook into that using `hook_form_alter` but the button doesn't seem to have been created yet, so I can't attach the AJAX handler.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately, you can't use #ajax because managed_file uses it internally for its own purposes.

Comment: Is there any way to it's internal ajax??